# Is it Possible to play movies in queue using AVPlayer...?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, ios4

i have to play movies one after another(queue), i try with MPMoviePlayerController by setting content url but flick is there.

Is it possible with AVPlayer..?

if possible any sample or tutorial

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

Look at AVQueuePlayer which is introduced 4.1

Comment: ya i done it .... http://cocoabugs.blogspot.com/2010/12/playing-movies-or-videos-in-queue-using.html